# c++ deducing a function pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is it possible to deduce a <s>non-type</s> *function pointer type* template argument <s>(function pointer)</s> from a function argument?

```
template <void(*fptr)()>
  void test(void(*fp)()) { fp(); }
```

to call this function I must explicitly declare the function template parameter:

```
test<somefunc>(somefunc);
```

I know I could also do it this way:

```
template <void(*fptr)()>
  void test() { fp(); }

test<somefunc>();
```

But I am just wondering if It is possible to do this way:

```
template <void(*fptr)()>
  void test() { fp(); }

test(somefunc);
```

Is it possible to declare in such a way that the compilier (GCC 4.7) will deduce from the function arguments?

Thanks alot in advance, been really wondering how to do this.
-Bryan

Comment: I misunderstood, but let me try something.

Comment: Broadly speaking, the code above should work. What problems are you having?

Comment: I think I have a reasonable solution (below)

Comment: You should review the code in the question, as it does not really make sense. In particular, in the last block `test` takes no arguments, but you are calling it with a function. At any rate, providing the argument would not cut it... the usual questions are: do you *really* need the function pointer to be a compile time argument? or would a runtime argument suffice (then you can infer the type of the function pointer, but pass the actual pointer to the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan, that seems to be quite eccentric mix of low-level C and C++. Why do you need that? Why not to use functors?

```
struct clean
{
    void operator() () 
    {
        // do something here        
    }
};

template <typename FuncType> void call_func(FuncType func)
{
    func();
}

// here is how to pass 'clean' to be called
call_func(clean());
```

More on functors, for example, here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html

Comment: That is awesome, I like this idea best

Comment: Gosh, I guess we were mistaken when we designed all of the standard library components that take function objects so that they work with pointers to functions. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker, Ive only been practicing c++ for about 8 months, am I missing something, the functor idea looks pretty cool, but I understand your a real expert on the topic. Should I look into something else?

Comment: @bryansammon - if a function object works for you, use it. I was responding more to the "eccentric mix of low-level C and C++" bit. The fundamental notion here is what the standard calls a "callable type". It encompasses function pointers, objects whose type has an `operator()`, pointers to member functions, and (don't ask!) pointers to member data. All of the function wrappers (except, for obvious reasons, `memfun` and `memfn`) handle any callable type.

Comment: @PeteBecker C standard library you mean? In standard library for C++ (STL), functors are used widely...

Comment: @PeteBecker - Thanks for responding back, I like the way functors solve this problem. I'll look at those function wrappers.

Comment: @SergeySirotkin - all the function wrappers in the C++ Standard Library (except, for obvious reasons, `memfun` and `memfn`) handle any callable type. That includes pointers to functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for clarification! My note about "eccentric" mix was mostly because (being in shoes of the beginner) I would prefer to go with something simpler than function pointers.

Comment: @SergeySirotkin - I suppose simplicity is in the eye of the beholder, but I would think that writing a function and using a pointer to it is simpler than writing a class with an overloaded function call operator.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to deduce a non-type template argument (function pointer) from a function argument?

No. Function arguments are runtime entities, and template arguments are compile-time entities.  To be deduced, such a template argument would have to be deduced at runtime, which is just not possible.

Comment: But in thsi case, (despite what he says) all he needs to do is deduce the function *type* from the function argument, which **is** available at compile-time.  The actual value is being passed as the argument.

Comment: Yeah, judging from the accepted answer that seems like it, despite the fact that the question starts with "Is it possible to deduce a *non-type* template argument (...)". I guess it was another case of the XY problem... sigh.

Answer (score 1):

I this this may do what you want:

Declare a base template which doesn't have a function type yet:

```
template <typename T> void test(T fp) { printf("function signature not supported\n"); }
```

Specialise for function types (mostly number of arguments):

```
typedef void(fptr0)();
template <> void test(fptr0 fp) { fp(); }
typedef void(fptr1)(int);
template <> void test(fptr1 fp) { fp(1); }
```

Declare some test functions with different signatures:

```
void myfn0() { printf("hi 0\n"); }
void myfn1(int x) { printf("hi 1:%i\n",x); }
void myfnD(float y) { printf("hi D %f\n",y); }
```

Now execute them:

```
int main(int,char**) {
   test(myfn0);
   test(myfn1);
   test(myfnD);
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
hi 0
hi 1:1
function signature not supported
```

Comment: I suspect this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Yea, I like the functor idea better. I was looking for doing something like you added, but without the explicit template parameters when you call the function

Comment: just for fun, try adding these templates to the mix: `template <typename E> void test(void(*fp)(E)) { printf("function type for 1-arg signature not supported\n"); }
template <typename E, typename F> void test(void(*fp)(E,F)) { printf("function type for 2-arg signature not supported
\n"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*fptr)();

void f() {
    std::cout << "hello, world\n";
}

template <class fptr> void g(fptr fp) {
    fp();
}

int main() {
    g(f);
    return 0;
}
```